# Navigation drawer with different activities or fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I will be starting with a, new app development.As i am new to android development, i wanted a suggestion.In my app i will be using a navigation drawer.Now i am confused that whether to use different activities or fragments.Also i wanted to make a navigation drawer common to all the activites without written the drawer code in all the activities.Please can some one help me which is the better way

1. To use one activities and multiple fragments or
2. one activity associated with a fragments.
3. Also how to use common navigation drawer code(along with actionBar) in all the activities

Comment: It depends. Will you have more than two different fragments?

Comment: yes i wil b having it

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is having a `BaseActivity` that extends `ActionBarActivity` and has the `DrawerLayout` and a `FrameLayout` that serves as a container to your current `Fragment`. It also has the code to put the `DrawerLayout` functioning and has an abstract method that changes the `Fragment` inside it. Like this:

```
public abstract void putFragment();
```

inside `onCreate()` method, the last call you make is `putFragment()`;

Then you will have as many Activities you want that will extend this `BaseActivity` and will implement `putFragment()` method. What they will do there is change the `Fragment` in the `FrameLayout` container. It means you have one `Fragment` for each sub `Activity` of `BaseActivity`.

You do not need to implement onCreate() method in your subActivities, because they inherit the parent `Activity` layout. Just implement putFragment() method so you have control on the current Fragment. Inside onCreateView() of each Fragment, do your app logic.

About the DrawerLayout, you just have to implement a `CallBack` in each of your SubActivities to handle a click in the `DrawerLayout`, and then execute a method like `selectDrawerItem()`, that starts the desired Sub `Activity`.

Comment: You should first try to implement it and research. Then explain what obstacles you are facing

Comment: Ok not an issue sir :).One more thng sir,is it better to use 1 activity and many frags  or 1 activity associated with each frags??

Comment: The second approach seems to be more scalable to me.